# Combined translational and rotational meshing in gmsh

Tags: mesh-generation, mesh, gmsh

For a flow simulation I am trying to reproduce a specific screw element design for an intermeshing co-rotating twin-screw extruder. I am using gmsh (v2.16) where the element is made from a 2D surface with a combined translational and rotational `extrude` command. The 2D sufrace is a simple shape as seen on the left in the picture below:

[image]

This shape is extruded translationally by 1 unit and rotationally by 360 degrees simulateneously to get the shape on the right which results in a screw thread.

Unfortunately, the resulting mesh contains 'distortions' which show up as holes along the extruded lines running across the length of the screw.

I tried refining the mesh, but the holes do not disappear. How do i get a smooth surface using this extrusion process?

[image]

The geometry file:

```
// inputs
length = 1;
pitch = 1;
alpha_i = Pi/3; // intermesh angle [0,Pi/2]
alpha_f = alpha_i; // flight angle
alpha_t = Pi/2 - alpha_f; // tip angle
alpha_r = alpha_t; // root angle

// based on unit screw diameter
Cd = Cos(alpha_i/2);  // centerline distance
Dr = 2*Cd-1; // root diameter
Hc = 1-Cd; // channel depth
Ih = Sin(alpha_i/2)/2; // intermesh height

lc = 0.1;
offset_x = Cd/2; // from x=0
offset_y = 0; // from y=0

// first screw

c1p0 = newp; // center point 
Point(c1p0) = {-offset_x+0, offset_y+0, 0, lc};

angle = alpha_t/2;
xt1 = 1/2*Cos(angle);
yt1 = 1/2*Sin(angle);

angle = angle + alpha_f;
xr1 = Dr/2*Cos(angle);
yr1 = Dr/2*Sin(angle);

angle = angle + alpha_r;
xr2 = Dr/2*Cos(angle);
yr2 = Dr/2*Sin(angle);

angle = angle + alpha_f;
xt2 = 1/2*Cos(angle);
yt2 = 1/2*Sin(angle);

angle = angle + alpha_t;
xt3 = 1/2*Cos(angle);
yt3 = 1/2*Sin(angle);

angle = angle + alpha_f;
xr3 = Dr/2*Cos(angle);
yr3 = Dr/2*Sin(angle);

angle = angle + alpha_r;
xr4 = Dr/2*Cos(angle);
yr4 = Dr/2*Sin(angle);

angle = angle + alpha_f;
xt4 = 1/2*Cos(angle);
yt4 = 1/2*Sin(angle);

c1p1 = newp; Point(c1p1) = {-offset_x+xt1, offset_y+yt1, 0, lc};
c1p2 = newp; Point(c1p2) = {-offset_x+xr1, offset_y+yr1, 0, lc};
c1p3 = newp; Point(c1p3) = {-offset_x+xr2, offset_y+yr2, 0, lc};
c1p4 = newp; Point(c1p4) = {-offset_x+xt2, offset_y+yt2, 0, lc};
c1p5 = newp; Point(c1p5) = {-offset_x+xt3, offset_y+yt3, 0, lc};
c1p6 = newp; Point(c1p6) = {-offset_x+xr3, offset_y+yr3, 0, lc};
c1p7 = newp; Point(c1p7) = {-offset_x+xr4, offset_y+yr4, 0, lc};
c1p8 = newp; Point(c1p8) = {-offset_x+xt4, offset_y+yt4, 0, lc};

c1a = newc; Circle(c1a) = {c1p2,c1p0,c1p3};
c1b = newc; Circle(c1b) = {c1p4,c1p0,c1p5};
c1c = newc; Circle(c1c) = {c1p6,c1p0,c1p7};
c1d = newc; Circle(c1d) = {c1p8,c1p0,c1p1};

// flank areas
alpha = -1/2*((xt1-xr1)*(xt1-xr1)+(yt1-yr1)*(yt1-yr1))/(yt1-yr1);
beta = -(xt1-xr1)/(yt1-yr1);
x0 = xr1 + alpha*beta/(1+beta*beta)*(1-Sqrt(1-(1+1/(beta*beta))*(1-Cd*Cd/(alpha*alpha))));
y0 = yr1 - alpha - beta*(xr1-x0);

p = newp; Point(p) = {-offset_x+x0, offset_y+y0, 0, lc};
c1e = newc; Circle(c1e) = {c1p1,p,c1p2};

p = newp; Point(p) = {-offset_x-x0, offset_y+y0, 0, lc};
c1f = newc; Circle(c1f) = {c1p3,p,c1p4};

p = newp; Point(p) = {-offset_x-x0, offset_y-y0, 0, lc};
c1g = newc; Circle(c1g) = {c1p5,p,c1p6};

p = newp; Point(p) = {-offset_x+x0, offset_y-y0, 0, lc};
c1h = newc; Circle(c1h) = {c1p7,p,c1p8};

ll = newl; Line Loop(ll) = {c1f, c1b, c1g, c1c, c1h, c1d, c1e, c1a};
s = newl; Plane Surface(s) = {ll};

Extrude {{0,0,length}, {0,0,1}, {-offset_x, -offset_y, 0}, 2*Pi*pitch*length} {
  Surface{s};
}
```

**Update**: Using @nicoguaro answer I was able to produce the following geometry in FREECAD:

[image]

However, as shown the ellipses are joined by curves which really should be straight lines. Refining by adding more slices improves this but also increases the computational cost significantly. This is only one screw element of a screw containing approximatly 30 of these elements. This quickly becomes too much to render. Anyway to connect with straight lines rather than curves?

Comment: I don't understand what is the geometry of what you are trying to do. Do you need to use gmsh o can you use another CAD for the geometry generation?

Comment: @nicoguaro - I have made some updates to the question, hopefully the geometry is clear now. I am not set on gmsh but prefer it as i do want to be able to design parametrically. I have tried OpenSCAD (and similar) and Blender but those I wasn't able to produce useable STL files for my simulation.

Comment: @ngluigi, did you  manage to export the geometry? I just downloaded the last version for Linux and I can't export the geometry.

Comment: @nluigi If you have succeeded to create the geometry with OpenSCAD, export it as CSG, import the CSG with FreeCAD and export as STEP or IGES. As the final step, import the STEP or IGES with salome and create the mesh. A little bit convoluted, but you seem to already have the geometry in OpenSCAD.

Comment: The curvature of the features that you're trying to mesh is far too high to capture with such coarse linear elements. You need to refine the mesh so that it has enough points on the boundary to faithfully represent the geometry that you want. Another thing to try (if you're not already) might be to use quadratic elements, which are better able to represent curved surfaces.

Comment: Have you tried with PyGmsh? Check the example [here](https://github.com/nschloe/pygmsh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot visualize your geometry properly using Gmsh, or export it. I generated something similar using FreeCAD. Maybe you can modify this script for your purposes.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
import FreeCAD as FC
import Draft
from numpy import sin, cos, pi

nturns = 1
nslices = 20
length = 10
width = 20
height = 60
dz = height/nslices
place = FC.Placement()
dang = 2*pi*nturns/(nslices - 1)
slices = []
for k in range(nslices):
    ang = k*dang
    place.Rotation = (0, 0, sin(ang/2), cos(ang/2))
    place.Base = FC.Vector(-length/2, -width/2, k*dz)
    slices.append(Draft.makeEllipse(10, 20, place))

doc = FC.ActiveDocument
loft = doc.addObject('Part::Loft','Loft')
loft.Sections = slices
loft.Solid = True
loft.Ruled = True
```

Comment: I am using the latest gmsh (v2.16) and have no problems visualizing and exporting (except for the distortions). Maybe try commenting out the extruder command. Your solutions looks promising, I will export the geometry and see if my simulation software will accept the exported STL.

Comment: I have update my question with info concerning your answer, please have a look.

Comment: @nluigi, did you try editing the script in FreeCAD setting up `loft.Ruled = False`? I think it produces what you want: plane surfaces.

Comment: @AntonMenshov - That is exactly what i need, thx!

Answer (score -1):

I would really use a commercial tool for your complicated geometry. I suggest Comsol.

I know this does not directly answer your question, but I have recently been in your shoes (I needed to create a 3D mesh for a non-trivial geometry), and I wasted so much time writing the appropriate .geo file. At the end, Gmsh was not even able to recombine the 3D mesh into tetrahedrons.

On the other hand, I have been able to produce the desired mesh with Comsol almost immediately.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. Unfortunately, I don't have access to commercial CAD and don't know if i can justify buying a license. Are there no freely available CAD programs which can do complex geometries? It doesn't even seem such a difficult geometry, it's basically a twisted stick

Comment: I know I shouldn't say this, but why don't you first download a "freely available" version of Comsol? Just to try the software and see if it fits your purpose. If it works for you, you can then think about getting a license e.g. through an academic institution?